# Names for different Javascript Object Notation

Tags: javascript

Is there a name for describing the different ways you can define an object in Javascript?

There is this method which is more 'class-like' :

```
function MyObject() {

    this.aMethod= new function(){
    };

    this.anotherMethod = new function(){
    };
}
```

And this other technique which is more 'dynamic'.

```
MyObject = new Object();
MyObject.aMethod= new function(){
};
MyObject.anotherMethod = new function(){
};
```

I have been using both of these techniques in various ways, and i understand the benefits of each, but for the life of me, I don't have any idea how to call these two techniques when discussing this with colleauges.

Do these techniques have names?

Comment: The `new`s before the function expressions are technically valid, but the result would be that `aMethod` (and `anotherMethod`) refer to empty objects instead of functions.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case `MyObject` is a **constructor function**, since it is supposed to be called with `new`:

```
var obj = new MyObject();
```

In the second case, `MyObject` is just an object and you assign properties to it. It does not have a special name.

Note that in both cases `MyObject` has different values. `MyObject` in the second case is equivalent to `obj`.

A third way is to use an object initilizer or "object literal":

```
var obj = {
    aMethod: function(){},
    anotherMethod: function(){}
};
```

Comment: thanks, so key thing to remember is 'constructor function', normal object, and 'object literal'

Comment: BTW quick question, can i use the NEW when i have an object literal aMethod= new function(){}; ? And whats the difference?

Comment: Whenever you have `new` + function reference, you are actually *calling* the function as a constructor function. So `aMethod = new function(){};` is equivalent to `aMethod = {}`, i.e. assigning an empty object to the property or variable. In which context this is executed does not matter. You can use it if that's what you want. But if you actually want to assign a function (which the property name `aMethod` somehow indicates) then using `new` is just wrong. If I want a variable to contain the string `"foo"`, I'm not going to assign the number `5` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is an **Object Constructor**, while the second is simply adding public methods as properties to an object. As a side note, for an even more "class-like" behavior take a look at the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript):

```
var MyObject = (function() {

  var privateStaticVariable = 0;

  var my = function() {
    var self = this;

    var privateInstanceVariable = 0;

    function privateInstanceMethod() {

    }

    self.publicInstanceVariable = 0;

    self.publicInstanceMethod = function() {

    };
  };

  function privateStaticMethod() {

  };

  return my;
});
```

Comment: so module pattern gives you ability to define private and public methods?

Comment: Yes, anything attached to the `self` object within the constructor can be accessed publicly, while other variables and functions remain private. Useful for providing proper encapsulation in JavaScript.